# сборка массива nodejs express mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Народ привет, я только учусь яве скрипт , пожалуйста пдскажите , ответ правильный никак не найду

если сделать console.log(тут row ); то в консоль выводит все массивы, а если делаю как в коде ниже, то отдает в ответе только первый массив, остальных нет

```
app.get('/assets/', (request, response) => {

        const ass = 'SELECT currency,name_es,cmcID,canWithdraw,canDeposit,minWithdrawal,maxWithdrawal,makerFee,takerFee FROM currencies WHERE is_active = "Y" AND is_crypto = "Y"';

    var assetss={};
    pool.query(ass , function(error, rows){
        assetss = rows;
        funcrows(assetss);
        });
        function funcrows(assetss) {
        for (var i = 0; i < assetss.length; i++) {
    var row = assetss[i];
    response.send({symbol:row.currency, name:row.name_es, lastUpdateTimestamp: new Date(),cmcID: row.cmcID,canWithdraw:row.canWithdraw, canDeposit:row.canDeposit, minWithdrawal:row.minWithdrawal, maxWithdrawal:row.maxWithdrawal, makerFee:row.makerFee, takerFee:row.takerFee});
        }
}


});
```

что я могу делать не так тут? вроде кода та с гулькин нос

мне нужно чтобы в итоге я выдал json ответ

Comment: Нужно в `for` сформировать массив, а затем вернуть его в `response.send`. Связано это с тем, что `.send()` можно вызывать только один раз. Можно использовать `.write()`, после чего самому вызвать `end()`

Comment: а кодом не подскажешь?? если я после фор делаю, то получаю только последний массив тогда

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так

```
app.get('/assets/', (request, response) => {

    const ass = 'SELECT currency,name_es,cmcID,canWithdraw,canDeposit,minWithdrawal,maxWithdrawal,makerFee,takerFee FROM currencies WHERE is_active = "Y" AND is_crypto = "Y"';
    function funcrows(assetss) {
       const formattedRows = []
       for (var i = 0; i < assetss.length; i++) {
             cosnt row = assetss[i];
             formatedRows.push({symbol:row.currency, name:row.name_es, lastUpdateTimestamp: new Date(),cmcID: row.cmcID,canWithdraw:row.canWithdraw, canDeposit:row.canDeposit, minWithdrawal:row.minWithdrawal, maxWithdrawal:row.maxWithdrawal, makerFee:row.makerFee, takerFee:row.takerFee});
       }
       return formatedRows;
    }

       pool.query(ass , function(error, rows){
            const assets = funcrows(assetss);
            response.send(assets)
       }
   }


});
```